# Google places API is working on emulator but crashing on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-places-api

I have been developing android app and while using **google places api**, it was working fine. All the expected results are retrieved from `HTTP` request when i run on **emulator**. But when i exported it using release key for maps to the device, it crashed `unfortunately app stopped working`. I found that the problem is with the Google places api retrieving results and the error code is ZERO results sometimes and INVALID request.

I tried every possible way to resolve this, but could not resolve this issue. This is what the code looks like:

```
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String searchtypes) throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            //request.getUrl().put("rankby",  "distance");
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(searchtypes != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", searchtypes);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            //Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {
            //Log.v("reference " , reference);
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);
            Log.v("place successfully bought " , place.result.name);
            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("TreasureRun");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

The above code are present in GooglePlaces.java file and it is called from async task present in java2 file.

The code in java2 file is:

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
 // creating Places class object 
 String taskstatus;
 googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
 try {
     String keyword = "cafe|restaurant";
     double radius = 1000; // 1000 meters 
     nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
     gps.getLongitude(), radius, keyword);
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
taskstatus = "done";
return taskstatus;
}
```

but what was happening is the when i call:

```
status = nearPlaces.status;
```

I guess the status is not  "Ok" in real device and it is crashing. But in emulator it works perfect and smooth

I tried for many days. Any one please help me

Thanks
Naveen

Comment: Post error logcat so we can help you more.